# E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported post

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

type here

Hello! I am tring to run my android app and login into facebook account but when i run it i get 2 errors and i can't find a way to solve them.
The errors i get are:

1. E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported post request. Object with ID '1234' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%7D)
2. E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.}

I am using the latest android studio version for this and for Facebook sign in i am using this  code:

```
package com.example.whatarewegoingtoeattoday;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FacebookSignInActivity extends LoginActivity {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        //mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));


        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookSignInActivity.this, "" +task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookSignInActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I watched many tutorials on youtube and i did the same as them, but my code it is still not working.
Please help me! :)